# Finding out the names of files in a directory

Tags: java, file-io

I am exporting objects in serializable form to the directory containing the src, build files. there are groups which share the start of their filenames, e.g.

```
lounge - 1,0
lounge - 2,4
dining room - 3,5
dining room - 4,6
dining room 5,2
```

I need to make an array list of all the groups so in this case an array containing lounge and dining room. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

There is the method `File.list()`, which will give you a list of all file names in a directory. Loop through this list, and extract the prefixes from each file name, put them into a set.

Answer (score 0):

`new File(dir).list()` returns array that contains all files in the directory.
Then you can iterate over the array and check something like:
`file.getName().startsWith()`.

You can also use `FileFilter` when calling `list()` but it will require calling list for each file group separately.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to get access to the files in the main java directory without typing out a specified path? only I'd like to keep this platform independent...

Comment: You can use `new File("./src").list();` for example, to get the contents of the /src directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of files using `File.list()`, then generate a list of unique prefixes by adding the names to a `HashSet`, something like this:

```
String[] fileList = new File("./src").list();
HashSet hset = new HashSet();
for(String s : fileList){
  hset.add(s.substring(0,s.length()-6));// assumes all names follow this pattern...
}
System.out.println(hset.toString());
```